# Count how many files are attached to many inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a code that, when the user clicks on an input (type="file"), creates another input. I want to count the number of **all** the files attached to **all** the inputs, not just one.
Actually my code just counts the files in the first input, not the total number oh them:

```
<div class="upload-container">
  <input type="file" multiple="multiple" class="upload" onclick="boomFunction(this)">
</div>
<p id="total_count"></p>

<script>
function boomFunction(obj) {
            $(".upload-container").append("<input type='file' multiple='multiple' class='upload' onclick='boomFunction(this)'>");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
              $('.upload-container .upload').change(function () {
                $('#total_count').text(this.files.length + " files selected");
              });
            });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bf2tcu5g/

Comment: `id="upload"` should be `class="upload"`. Then just iterate over all `.upload`s and count the files.

Comment: You are right, I corrected it, but also with class="upload" the code doesn't work

Comment: you need to use `onchange` event listener, rather than `onclick`

Comment: No, also with onchange the code doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As you add dynamic elements to document, you have to change the syntax of selector to this:

   ```
   $(document).on("change",'.upload-container .upload',function () {})
   ```
2. You should loop through all `.upload` elements to count the total files.
3. there was a mistake that you set `id="upload"` to new elements. It should be `class="upload"`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upload-container">
  <input type="file" multiple="multiple" class="upload" onclick="boomFunction(this)">
</div>
<p id="total_count"></p>

<script>
function boomFunction(obj) {
  $(".upload-container").append("<input type='file' multiple='multiple' class='upload' onclick='boomFunction(this)'>");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("change",'.upload-container .upload',function () {
      var total=0;
     $(".upload").each(function(){
       total=total+this.files.length;
     })
     $('#total_count').text(total + " files selected");
  });
});
</script>
```